# Unexpected Web-Application closing immediately after starting

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

These are the current dependencies included in my web application.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.10.0")
}
```

Every time I run the application I get the following error:

```
2019-09-30 13:32:38.385  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] unito.taas.project.ProjectApplicationKt  : Starting ProjectApplicationKt on LAPTOP-K1DHEJQ6 with PID 17104 (C:\Users\beppe\Desktop\project\TAAS_project\project\build\classes\kotlin\main started by beppe in C:\Users\beppe\Desktop\project\TAAS_project)
2019-09-30 13:32:38.388  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] unito.taas.project.ProjectApplicationKt  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-30 13:32:38.444  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-09-30 13:32:39.177  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-30 13:32:39.263  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 77ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
2019-09-30 13:32:39.785  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-09-30 13:32:39.976  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-09-30 13:32:40.045  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-09-30 13:32:40.127  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
2019-09-30 13:32:40.128  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-30 13:32:40.317  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-09-30 13:32:40.734  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2019-09-30 13:32:41.419  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-30 13:32:41.439  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-09-30 13:32:43.049  INFO 17104 --- [  restartedMain] unito.taas.project.ProjectApplicationKt  : Started ProjectApplicationKt in 5.053 seconds (JVM running for 5.806)
2019-09-30 13:32:43.063  INFO 17104 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-30 13:32:43.068  INFO 17104 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-09-30 13:32:43.073  INFO 17104 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

How can I avoid the application closing?

EDIT:
The following is my SpringBoot annotated class

```
package unito.taas.project

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class ProjectApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ProjectApplication>(*args)
}
```

Comment: How does your SpringBootApplication class look like?

Comment: I added the SpringBoot annotated class